# indefinite integral of $\cos(x) / x$?

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How can I evaluate ;

$$\int \frac{\cos(x)}{x} \, dx $$

I tried to do partial integration but it became to an infinite loop of partial integrations

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html

Comment: We can't integrate it. That's why we make functions for these kinds of problems this one is $Ci(x)$

Comment: @Nikunj W can integrate them, but not find closed form expressions in "simple functions"

Comment: $\mathrm{Ci}$ is a special function known as [trigonometric integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral). You can find more info at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos%28x%29%2Fx+dx. There exist series expansions that can approximate this function very well.

Comment: @LaurentDuval By not being able to integrate them, I only meant being unable to find a closed form for them.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the Taylor series expansion for $\cos x$
\begin{align*}\cos x &= 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \cdots \\
\implies \frac{\cos x}{x} &= \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{4!} - \frac{x^5}{6!} + \cdots \\
\therefore \int \frac{\cos x}{x} &= ln\ x - \frac{x^2}{2 \times 2!} + \frac{x^4}{4 \times 4!} - \frac{x^6}{6 \times 6!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{2k}}{(-1)^{k}\times2k \times (2k)!} + \cdots
\end{align*}
This sum approaches zero so that the indefinite integral is $ln(x)$ up to an integration constant.  Moreover, if the terminals of integration are say $a$ and $b$ (not zero or infinity), the definite integral would be $ln(a)-ln(b)$.  Where the terminals include zero or infinity, the Trigonometric Integral $Ci(x)$ or $Cin(x)$ need to be used.

Comment: So if I want to find $$\int_0^a f(x) \,dx,$$, then I get ln0 in somewhere ?

Comment: @OnurTırtır At $x=0$, $\frac{cos0}{0}$ tends to infinity, so the divergence of its integral makes sense

Comment: This is the incorrect taylor expansion of cosx it alternates between positive and negative terms.