# Solve: $\int \frac{\cos x}{x} dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Please help me solve this question. I have tried using series expansion, but I am not getting an finite answer.

Comment: This is a special function : the cosine integral. Google for it.

Comment: [It's not elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral).

Comment: Thanks, but that's a definite integral. Can we find it's indefinite integral???

Comment: Apologies for late comment, but it is related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694748/indefinite-integral-of-cosx-x/1694903#1694903

Comment: Possible duplicate of [indefinite integral of $\cos(x) / x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694748/indefinite-integral-of-cosx-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no closed form of this integral using elementary functions,but we can show an infinite series using Taylor expansion as an answer. In case you want to know more about the integral, you can find it [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html)

$\int \frac{\cos(x)}{x} dx=  \int( \frac{1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots}{x})dx = \int (\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots) dx= \ln(x) - \frac{x^2}{2\cdot2!}+\frac{x^4}{4\cdot4!}-\frac{x^6}{6\cdot6!}+\cdots$

So,

$\int \frac{\cos(x)}{x} dx = \ln(x) - \frac{x^2}{2\cdot2!}+\frac{x^4}{4\cdot4!}-\frac{x^6}{6\cdot6!}+\cdots$

Or more generally, $\int \frac{\cos(x)}{x} dx = \ln(x) + \Sigma_{r=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{r}\frac{x^{2r}}{2r\cdot(2r)!}$

Hope this helps !